# AES decryption in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file encrypted with AES128 symmetric algo. How to configure in spark to decode the file?

I tried to load the file like below and then invoke the custom function to do the decryption. But the decryption always fails. Looks like the encrypted binary content changes somehow after loading through spark. How to avoid it?

```
val dec = spark.sparkContext.textFile("inputFile")
dec.coalesce(1, shuffle=true).saveAsTExtFile("path")
```

Exception while decryption the save file

```
Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
java.lang.SecurityException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Spark itself does not have a decryption API so you will have to do a line by line (or cell by cell in case of dataframes) decryption.

Code wise you can do something like below,

Assuming text file from example,

```
val sparkSession = ???
import sparkSession.implicits._

// Read text file as data set
val df = sparkSession.read.text("/path/to/files/").as[String]

// Create UDF for decryption
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

def decrypt_text: UserDefinedFunction = {
udf((str: String) => {
 // Decryption logic
})
}

// Use UDF to decrypt
val decDF = df.withColumn("decrpytedText", decrypt_text(col("value")))

// View results
decDF.show(false)
```

Comment: how to decrypt the whole file instead of string by string?

Comment: After decryption, the value can be a CSV, JSON, XML (or even binary content such as Avro or Parquet). How you flatmap a whole data file into separate records, using Spark, the same way it would do with spark.read.csv or spark.read.avro, etc. ?

Comment: @Minisha, you should use a RDD with sparkContext.binaryFiles() or using DataFrame with spark.read.format("binaryFile").load